# ElasticSearch match a word without compound words

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to search on Elastic a full word like `home` but not compound words like `homeland`.
Using this query:

```
{
                "query": {
                    "match": {
                        "text": {
                            "query": term,
                            "minimum_should_match": "100%"
                          }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

will both match `home` and `homeland` or `hometown` etc. How to restrict the match to the input word token only?

**NOTE**. The word maybe in a different language, so I cannot specify something like a english analyzer, because I do not know the language of the word a priori.

Comment: I have tried `fuzziness: 0`, not sure if this is the best solution though.

Comment: With some standard analyzer, it should already work as expected. I guess you use a ngram analyzer. could you post your mapping?